# Como cambio el estilo de un texto que no tiene ninguna etiqueta en HTML

Tags: html

Quiero seleccionar un texto pero sin seleccionar directamente al body, básicamente editar un texto así pero con una selección directa sin tomar en cuenta sus etiquetas padre.

Comment: Hola, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta con algo de código para un mejor entendimiento del problema que formulas. Hasta donde entiendo, lo que quieres es dar estilo a un texto que está directamente en la etiqueta body del HTML y no dentro de alguna otra, verdad?

Comment: Si un texto no esta en una etiqueta no es parte de `html`, asi que no puedes, siempre debes de trabajar bajo etiquetas y asi poder darle estilo con `css`

Answer (score 0):

Para agregarle estilo al texto tienes que colocarlo en la etiqueta. Si no está en una, no se le podrá hacer estilos. Debes meterlo en una etiqueta `<p>` si es un  texto simple y en un `<h1>` al `<h6>` para encabezados además de agregarles una clase o un id o también un atributo `style`.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<!--Este <p> tiene el atributo "style"-->
<p style="aqui el estilo">Este es un texto</p>

<!--Este <p> tiene una clase-->
<p class="ejemplo">Este es un texto</p>

<!--Este <p> tiene un id-->
<p id="ejemplo">Este es un texto</p>
```

Solo de estas maneras le puedes estilizar. Espero te sirva.